# Unconstrained Optimal Control - $J = \frac{1}{2}x^2(2) + \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{2}(u^2 - 2xu)dt$

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, real-numbers, optimal-control

I've been given the following unconstrained optimal control problem, but I feel like I've made a mistake at some point.

> The system $\dot x = -x + u$, where u = u(t) is not subject to any constraint, is to be controlled from $x(0) = 1$ in such a way that; $$J = \frac{1}{2}x^2(2) + \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{2}(u^2 - 2xu)dt$$ is minimised. Find the optimal control.

To begin with, I set my Hamiltonian as follows;
$$H' = xu - \frac{u^2}{2} + \lambda(u-x)$$

With the costate equation;
$$\dot \lambda = \frac{- \partial H'}{\partial x} = -u + \lambda$$

Now, we want to maximise $H'$ as a function of $u$, so;
$$0 = \frac{\partial H'}{\partial u} = x - u + \lambda$$

So, now, I have $u = x + \lambda$, $\dot x = -x + u$, and $\dot \lambda = -u + \lambda$.

Now, we can replace the $u$ in the latter two functions to get;
$$\dot x = \lambda$$
$$\dot \lambda = -x$$

Then, we have;
$$\ddot x = \dot \lambda$$
$$\implies \ddot x = -x$$
$$\implies x(t) = A \sin(t) + B \cos(t)$$
For some constants $A, B \in \Re$.

Now, we're given the initial condition $x(0) = 1$, so we can use this to show that $B = 1$.

Then, we have the following;
$$x(t) = A \sin(t) + \cos(t)$$
$$\lambda(t) = A \cos(t) - \sin(t)$$

Now, because of the way my $J$ was set up, I now need to use a transversality condition;
$$\lambda(t_1) = \frac{-\partial g }{\partial x}$$

Setting $t_1 = 2$, and $g = \frac{-x^2}{2}$, we get;
$$\lambda(2) = -x(2)$$
$$\implies A \cos(2) - \sin(2) = -A\sin(2) - \cos(2)$$
$$\implies A = \frac{\sin(2) - \cos(2)}{\sin(2) + \cos(2)}$$

To me, this just seems overly complex?? Regardless, I can get an equation for the optimal control now;

$$u = x + \lambda = (A-1)\sin(t) + (A+1)\cos(t)$$
With the $A$ term as defined above.

Does this seem correct?? I can't really see a problem with my working, but my $A$ term just seems strange.

Comment: I think you are in my class, could you have a look at where I am going wrong on my attempt solution found here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/980490/time-optimal-control-to-the-origin-for-two-first-order-odes-trying-to-take-con/996577#996577